# Python: replace every letter except the nth letters in a string with a period(or another character)

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have looked at the replace every nth letter and could not figure out the reverse. I started with this and quickly realized it would not work:

```
s = input("Enter a word or phrase: ")
l = len(s)

n = int(input("choose a number between 1 and %d: " %l))

print (s[0] + "." * (n-1)+ s[n]+ "." * (n-1) + s[n*2])
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the intended result for `s = "abcdefghi"` and `n = 3`?

Answer (score 1):

Let `s` be the original string and `n` the position not to be replaced.

```
''.join (c if i == n else '.' for i, c in enumerate (s) )
```

Comment: If you only want to replace 1 character, it seems like concatenation and slicing might be quicker:   `''.join((s[:n], '.', s[n+1:]))`, although it might give strange-ish results if `n` is less than 0 or >= len(s).

Answer (score 1):

If the user enters `3`, I'm assuming you want to replace the third, sixth, ninth...letter, right? Remember that indices are counted from `0`:

```
>>> s = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
>>> remove = 3
>>> "".join(c if (i+1)%remove else "." for i,c in enumerate(s))
'ab.de.gh.jk.mn.pq.st.vw.yz'
```

Or, if you meant the opposite:

```
>>> "".join("." if (i+1)%remove else c for i,c in enumerate(s))
'..c..f..i..l..o..r..u..x..'
```

Comment: This doesn't replace anything, it omits.

Comment: I am not sure though, how to read the question. The text points to your solution. The code sample points to mine. Let's see what OP answers.

Comment: "Python: replace every letter except the nth letters"... There is only one nth letter...

Comment: @Hyperboreus: I think I had it completely backwards. Let's hope the OP clarifies things a bit...

Comment: To me it seems OP wants the second one, but with `i % remove` instead of `(i+1)%remove`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use reduce following way:

```
>>> s = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
>>> n=3
>>> print reduce(lambda i,x: i+x[1] if (x[0]+1)%n else i+".", enumerate(s), "")
ab.de.gh.jk.mn.pq.st.vw.yz
>>> print reduce(lambda i,x: i+"." if (x[0]+1)%n else i+x[1], enumerate(s), "")
..c..f..i..l..o..r..u..x..
```

Answer (score 0):

Build from what you already know. You know how to find every `n`th character, and your result string will have all of those in it and no other character from the original string, so we can use that. We want to insert things *between* those, which is exactly what the str.join method does. You've already worked out that what to insert is `'.' * n-1`. So, you can do this:

```
>>> s = "abcdefghi"
>>> n = 3
>>> ('.' * (n-1)).join(s[::n])
'a..d..g'
```

The only trick is that you need to account for any characters *after* the last one that you want to leave in place. The number of those is the remainder when the highest valid index of `s` is divided by `n` - or, `(len(s) - 1) % n`. Which gives this slightly ugly result:

```
>>> ('.' * (n-1)).join(s[::n]) + '.' * ((len(s) - 1) % n)
'a..d..g..'
```

You probably want to use variables for the two sets of dots to help readability:

```
>>> dots = '.' * (n - 1)
>>> end_dots = '.' * ((len(s) - 1) % n)
>>> dots.join(s[::n]) + end_dots
'a..d..g..'
```

Answer (score 0):

My tricky solution (I'll let you add comments):

```
s = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
n = 3
single_keep_pattern = [False] * (n - 1) + [True]
keep_pattern = single_keep_pattern * ( len(s) / n + 1)
result_list = [(letter if keep else '.') for letter, keep in zip(s, keep_pattern)]
result = ''.join(result_list)

print result
```

gives:

```
..c..f..i..l..o..r..u..x..
```